# Convert Delaunay triangulation to Voronoi diagram in 3d

Tags: geometry, computational-geometry, triangulation, voronoi

I can construct Delaunay triangulation using exact arithmetic ([https://www.cs.cmu.edu/~quake/robust.html](https://www.cs.cmu.edu/%7Equake/robust.html)). If I don't use exact arithmetic, then the algorithm may fail. The problem with exact arithmetic is that it creates too thin tetrahedra. Consequently, I cannot always calculate the center of a sphere described around tetrahedra. Sometimes a remote point is obtained, which cannot exactly be a vertex in the Voronoi diagram. How can the center of the sphere of very thin tetrahedra be adequately calculated? Or is it better not to use exact arithmetic, but then how to achieve the stability of the triangulation algorithm?

Comment: Center of circumscribed sphere is computed exactly if vertices are integers or rationals: http://rodolphe-vaillant.fr/entry/127/find-a-tetrahedron-circumcenter